# Predicate Logic - How Specific to Be When Converting From English Sentence

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

I'm learning predicate logic, and one of the tasks is to translate English statements into predicate logic. I'm struggling with understanding how specific you have to be.
Suppose you have a statement like "there exists a person who cannot run".
Are these both valid representations of that statement:

`∃x P(X) ∧ ¬R(X)` where `P(x)` means `x` is a person, and `R(x)` means `x` can run.

`∃x ¬R(x)` where `R(x)` means `x` can run, and the domain of `x` is all people

Another example with a more complex statement could be "Everybody knows someone who is a runner":

`∀x∃y P(x) ∧ P(y) ∧ R(y) ∧ KN(x, y)` where `P(x)` means `x` is a person, `R(x)` means `x` can run, and `KN(x, y)` means `x` and `y` know each other

`∀x∃y R(y) ∧ KN(x, y)` where `R(x)` means `x` can run, and `KN(x, y)` means `x` and `y` know each other and the domain of `x` and `y` is all people.

Are both of these valid and representative of the statement?

Comment: See examples in [Velleman's book](https://www.google.it/books/edition/How_to_Prove_It/lptwaMuAtBAC) (Ch.2 Quantificational Logic); usually, the domain (e.g. the "universe" of all people) is not specified.

Comment: But there are case, like that of [limit of a sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Definition), where we have different sorts of numbers: if we assume that the universe is that of *reals*, we need a predicate $N(x)$ to sort out the naturals.

Comment: Not much need to be said other tha what @MauroALLEGRANZA has already said. You need to be as specific as it is required to be unambiguous. If the domain is implicit, e.g. that the universe of discourse is people, then your sentences don't need to state each time that some x is a person. But if the domain is not specified, we tend to assume that it is the universe of all things. The same goes for other domains, such as number systems. If we're talking about the Reals, then you don't need to say that some x is a real number -- you just skip that, given it is assumed that it is a real number.

Comment: Just an additional note after the other comments: For any axiomatic system, mathematical rigour is of utmost importance. While language permits flexibility and involvement of external context, rigorous systems force you to define the context yourself. This is also the key idea behind many algorithmic theorem provers, like Lean.

Comment: I would translate it as: $\forall x [P(x) \to \exists y  [P(y) \land KN(x,y) \land R(y)]]$. I find that, while it may be more verbose, formally specifying the domain like this can simplify things.

Comment: ... It also does not assume a non-empty domain for predicate $P(x)$. You would have to add $\exists x [P(x)]$ to specify a non-empty domain.